# Combobox in C# - Updates both boxes at the same time when selecting an item in one of them

Tags: c#

I m trying to use 2 comboboxes to display coursecodes for my studenthandler program.

My Question is why the both the comboboxes are updated to my selected item when I select something in the list.

I m loading my comboboxes in the constructor and both the list are beeing loaded just fine, but when i run the program and choose something in the List the other combobox is also selected with the item that I choose in the first one.

Both the comboboxes uses diffrent list but the same method to load them is called, they don t have the same name or anything like that.

What could cause this?

The debugger runs trough both of these:

```
private void AllTheCourses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e) { }

private void AllCourseCodes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

Comment: can you give an example of your code?, you should have the Event OnSelectedChanged() or something like that set for both to the same event ... is it a web or win app?

Comment: Can you please post any relevant code (from both the aspx and aspx.cs pages)

Comment: can you please post some code to analyze?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you're assigning the same event to both comboboxes.

Try to debug the code.

You should bind each combobox to a different event handler. In each event handler, you can call a different fill method or the same one if that's what you want.

Comment: I already did that, but when i try to select something in the list the debugger runs trough both of these: 

private void AllTheCourses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void AllCourseCodes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

Comment: @Fredrick: post the code above in your question (for better formatting). What kind of application is this? WindowsForms or an ASP.NET app?